# Best Practices for Conditional Rendering with Button Click in Mixed Server and Client Components in Next.js 14

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering, app-router

I am working on a Next.js 14 project and facing a challenge with implementing conditional rendering. My setup includes a server component that contains both server and client child components. Specifically, I have a client component, `AddIngreso`, which contains a button. Upon clicking this button, I want to trigger conditional rendering to display other components.

The challenge I'm facing is the limitation that having a server component as the parent doesn't allow me to use hooks like `useState` for managing state changes triggered by the client component. I'm seeking advice on the best way to handle this scenario. Is there a recommended approach in Next.js for managing interactions and state changes between server and client components, especially when the parent component is a server component? Should I use custom events or a different pattern?

I'm looking for insights or best practices for achieving this kind of conditional rendering with a button click in a client component within a server component context in Next.js 14. Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Here's the structure of my JSX code:

```js
// Import necessary components
import AddFrequentIngreso from "./añadirFrecuenteIngreso";
import AddIngreso from "./añadirIngreso";
import FrequentIngresostabla from "./frequentIngresostablaDelMes";
import TablaIngresos from "./tablaIngresosDelMes";
const AñadirIngresoYFuente = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col sm:flex-row w-full">
      {/* First Column */}
      <div className="flex flex-col w-full sm:w-3/4 h-[62vh] overflow-y-auto">
        <h1 className="text-2xl font-semibold text-white text-center">
          Administrar nuevos ingresos
        </h1>
        <div className="overflow-y-auto">
          <TablaIngresos maxRows={5} />
        </div>
        <AddIngreso />
      </div>
      {/* Divider */}
      <div className="w-full sm:w-2 h-2 sm:h-auto bg-gray-300 dark:bg-gray-700 rounded-full my-2 sm:my-0"></div>
      {/* Second Column */}
      <div className="flex flex-col w-full sm:w-1/4 h-[62vh] overflow-y-auto">
        <h1 className="text-2xl font-semibold text-white text-center">
          Administrar fuentes de ingreso
        </h1>
        <div className="overflow-y-auto">
          <FrequentIngresostabla maxRows={5} />
        </div>
        <AddFrequentIngreso />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AñadirIngresoYFuente;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was under the impression that a client component couldn't have server components as children in any capacity. However, your insights clarified that it's indeed possible to pass server components as props within a client component. This realization has been pivotal in resolving my challenge. I truly appreciate your assistance and patience in helping me understand this crucial aspect of Next.js.